# Specifying what records are returned from database depending on certain field with Sequelize and MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to get the lastest records in a database.  I have a field with their category. I'm trying to get 20 records, 5 of the latest post in each category. What I mean is that it should return 20 latest records but 5 of each category since the latest 20 does not necessarily mean a balanced 5 of each category. Basically what I have below, but I feel there's a better way and wasn't able to see it from reading the Sequelize docs. Thanks guys, I really appreciate it! Pardon the pseudocode. I have 4 categories. and im actually also sorting by createdAt timestamp field with limits and attributes and other checks/ error handling that I have not included for the sake of readability.

```
Posts.findAll({ where: { category: "Tech"}})
.then(techPosts => {
     Posts.findAll({where:{category: "Science"},})
     .then(sciencePosts => {
          //actually 2 more nested findAlls before sending
          const posts = [...techPosts, ...sciencePosts]
          res.status(200).json(posts).end();
     })
})
```

Comment: The simplest solution is to create 4 separate queries where each query selects 5 latest rows for one definite (hardcoded) category, and UNION ALL the queries outputs. use it if the categories list is static and won't be expanded in future. More complex solution (with dynamic categories list and/or rows per category amount) depends on precise MySQL version and may use subquery, CTE, window function... and it can be less effective.

Comment: PS. The simplest solution does not solve a problem: when some category contains less than 5 rows then total output will be more slim then needed (will contain less than 20 rows) and won't be expanded till needed 20 rows by adding more rows from another categories.

Comment: Thanks @Akina I will look into that, I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest fetching 5 different categories at the same time using "Promise.all".
The code would look like this:

```
const fetchTechPosts = () => {
  return Posts.findAll({ where: { category: "Tech"}})
}

const fetchSciencePosts = () => {
  return Posts.findAll({ where: { category: "Science"}})
}

const promises = Promise.all([fetchTech, fetchScience])
promises.then(posts => {
  res.status(200).json(posts).end()
})
```